# How to find the combination of duplicate properties in Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object which has multiple properties . I want to check before pushing the other object if the objects in array already has the same combination of property values of the new object.

```
[ {
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" : 55,
  "TV" : 123,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" : 55,
  "TV" : 126,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" :33,
  "TV" : 26,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
} ]
```

New Object that has to be pushed

```
 {
      "mobile" : "6013456",
      "cars" :33,
      "TV" : 26,
      "bottle" : "Dummy",
    }
```

I want to check if the combination of cars and tv of new object is already present in the array cars+tv should always be unique, I don't want to push. SO the above object should not be pushed, if the object is

```
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" :33,
  "TV" : 29,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
}
```

then this can be pushed.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var carObj =    [ {
 "mobile" : "6014834",
 "cars" : 55,
 "TV" : 123,
 "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" : 55,
  "TV" : 126,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" :33,
  "TV" : 26,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
 } 
]

carObj.forEach(function(entry) {
   if (entry.cars != 33 && entry.TV != 26) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

You need to extend the default array method as follows which will check the duplicate based on `tv` and `cars` fields:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function ( needle ) {
   for (i in this) {
       if (this[i].cars === needle.cars 
           && this[i].TV === needle.TV) {
         return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Second:**

Before each insert of object, you need to check whether the object exists in the array if not exists, then add, the following section of code do that:

```
if(!arrayObj.contains(insertObj)) {
  arrayObj.push(insertObj);

}
```

Please use the following codes:

```js
var arrayObj = [{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" : 55,
  "TV" : 123,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" : 55,
  "TV" : 126,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
},
{
  "mobile" : "6014834",
  "cars" :33,
  "TV" : 26,
  "bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload",
} ];
Array.prototype.contains = function ( needle ) {
   for (i in this) {
       if (this[i].cars === needle.cars 
           && this[i].TV === needle.TV) {
         return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}

var insertObj = {"mobile" : "6014834","cars" :33,"TV" : 26,"bottle" : "2897621771 - Hand Unload"};
if(!arrayObj.contains(insertObj)) {
  arrayObj.push(insertObj);
  
}

console.log(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _ (Underscore) library for this sort of problems. It has a method called where. This method searches a collection for a specified key value pair and if the parameters match, returns them in an array.
You can invoke the method like this.

Lets say your new object is newObject.

```
var newObject = {
"mobile":someValue,
"cars":someValue2,
"TV":someValue3,
"bottle":someValue4
};

 if(_.where(carsAndTvs,{"cars":newObject.cars,"TV":newObject.TV}).length >0){
   //push object into array
   }
```

You can read up more on the method here

http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 0):

```
let coinciding = arr.findIndex(oldObj => {

     let keys = Object.keys(oldObj);    // property names in the oldObj

       // count how many properties have the same value:
     let propsEqual = keys.reduce((prev, key) => {
         return prev += (oldObj[key] === newObject[key] ? 1 : 0)
     }, 0);

     return propsEqual == keys.length;        
})
```

coinciding will be the index in the old array of the object with the same properties. If there are no coincidences it will be -1.